# Using external prisma client (from turborepo) in nestjs service (nextjs app works)

Tags: next.js, nestjs, prisma, monorepo, turborepo

I am currently building a monorepo app that uses turborepo, nextjs, nestjs and a shared prisma client.
The prisma client works in nextjs but not in nestjs (error on the bottom).

I have the following structure:

```
└── turbo
    └── apps
        └── nest
        └── web (next)
    └── packages
        └── database (prisma)
            ├── schema.prisma
            ├── package.json
            ├── index.ts
```

the database package looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "@repo/database",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "prisma": "^5.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.7.1"
  }
}
```

And the databse project exports a prisma singleton like this:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
export * from '@prisma/client';

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
    return new PrismaClient()
}

declare global {
    var prisma: undefined | ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>
}

const prisma = globalThis.prisma ?? prismaClientSingleton()

export default prisma

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalThis.prisma = prisma
```

Now in nextjs server context I can just use the prisma client as I wish when I put the @repo/database package as a normal dependency in the package.json

Example page:

```
import prisma from "@repo/database";


export default async function Page() {
    const users= await prisma.users.findMany();
    return <div>
        <UsersList data={(users as IUser[])}/>
    </div>
}
```

This works just fine, but in nestjs context I tried many things so far, my goal is to have a cron running that also fetches data from the shared prisma client.

My package json also has the @repo/database dependency and the app.module looks like:

```
// src/app.module.ts
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {CronService} from './cron/cron.service';
import {ScheduleModule} from "@nestjs/schedule";
import {CustomPrismaModule} from 'nestjs-prisma';
import {PrismaClient} from '@repo/database';

@Module({
    imports: [ScheduleModule.forRoot(), 
CustomPrismaModule.forRoot({
        name: 'PrismaDatabase',
        client: new PrismaClient(),
    }),],
    providers: [CronService],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

With the cron.service looking like:

```
// src/cron/cron.service.ts
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {Cron, CronExpression} from "@nestjs/schedule";
import {CustomPrismaService} from "nestjs-prisma";
import {PrismaClient} from '@repo/database';


@Injectable()
export class CronService {
    constructor(
        @Inject('PrismaDatabase') 
        private prisma: CustomPrismaService<PrismaClient>
    ) {}

    @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_30_SECONDS)
    async handleCron() {
        // Your logic here
        const res = await this.prisma.client.users.findMany();
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

When I try to run the nestjs server I get the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run start

> your-nest-app@0.0.1 start
> nest start               

Error: Cannot find module '@repo/database'
Require stack:
- C:\Workspace\xyz\turbo\apps\nest\dist\app.module.js
- C:\Workspace\xyz\turbo\apps\nest\dist\main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:1
5)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Workspace\xyz\turbo\apps\nest\src\app.module.t
s:6:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10) 
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
npm ERR! Lifecycle script `start` failed with error:         
npm ERR! Error: command failed                               
npm ERR!   in workspace: nest@0.0.1                 
npm ERR!   at location: C:\Workspace\xyz\turbo\apps\nest 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone have any insight on how to work with a shared prisma client in nestjs context? All ressources I have found so far lead me to the same error that the module could not be found.